# Facebook like-box not working, when i want to display group wall instead of a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

i want to display facebook group wall as like-box but it's not working.if i display page than it's work. Any one have idea how to display group wall as like-box tan plz let me know.
i want to display this wall:
http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=308734487787&v=wall

following is my code:-

```
 $<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <head>
  <title>Facebook post </title>

 </head>

 <body>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/group.php?gid=308734487787&v=wall" width="292" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="false"></fb:like-box> </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Like Box](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) is designed to be used with the Pages product. It doesn't display the wall of a group by design. There's no Social Plugin that does what you're looking for.